# Checking if a variable has been set is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, initialization, undefined

I am trying to set a variable initially only if it has not been set. For some reason the logic I'm using to determine whether the variable has been set seems to run even regardless of whether the variable has been set.

My code is

```
var l0 = -210;

function add(){
  var lThis;
  if (lThis == null){
     lThis = l0;
     console.log('set lThis to '+ lThis);
  }
  lThis ++;
}

var incrementInterval = setInterval(add, 33);
```

The console logs "set lThis to -210" every time the interval runs, so the "if (lThis == null)" seems to be doing nothing

See [example on codepen](http://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/XNOOma)

Comment: lThis, is a variable name local to the add function and will be initialized and / or re-declared each time the function is invoked. To avoid complications you can also declare lThis globally.  - And you never compare literals to null, unless you've nullified its handle manually and deliberately later on the code in order to reset its value. Even then, nullifying a variable that is supposed to carry a literal value is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setInterval function add is executed every 33ms from the start, do the whole function scope is recreated, including lThis. I suppose what you want to achieve is to add 1 on every call to lThis within function. One of ways to achieve that is using closure in the following way:

```
var l0 = -210;

function thunkAdd(){
  var lThis = l0;
  console.log('set lThis to '+ lThis);
  return function inc() {
    console.log(lThis);
    return lThis ++;
  }
}

var incrementInterval = setInterval(thunkAdd(), 33);
```

Note, this is the old way of writing JavaScript, with new ES6 syntax it can be achieved in much more compact form:

```
const l0=-210;

function *add() {
  let lThis = l0;
  while (true) yield lThis++;
}

const lAdd = add()
const incrementInterval = setInterval(() => {console.log(lAdd.next())}, 33);
```

Comment: That was quite helpful in incrementing the variable. I have a followup I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41232326/370407 . Maybe you'd have some insight there.

Answer (score 1):

`lThis` is a local variable in your example. So `lThis` will be reinitialized to `undefined` each time the function `add()` is called, and you will never reach `lThis++`. You probably want to move `lThis` outside of `add()`:

```
var lThis;

function add() {
  if (!lThis) {
     lThis = l0;
     console.log('set lThis to '+ lThis);
  }
  lThis++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `lThis` is a *local* variable, it exists (and created each time) only in the scope of `function add()`.
If you want to preserve a value of `lThis` during the `setInterval(...)` you should consider to move it to the global scope:

```
var lThis = null;

function add() {
    if (lThis == null) {
        lThis = -210
        console.log('set lThis to '+ lThis);
    }
    lThis++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`lThis` is a local variable. This variable would be reset to 'null' every 33ms, when `add()` gets called.

What about another global variable, like this:

```
var l0 = -210;
var lThis;

function add() {
  if (lThis == null) {
    lThis = l0;
  .......
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I think your whole code snippet needs a dramatic rewrite

```js
function add (x) {
  console.log(x)
  setTimeout(add, 33, x + 1)
}

let timeout = add(-210)
```

If you really want a global variable for some (probably bad) reason

```js
let x = -210

function add () {
  console.log(x)
  x = x + 1
}

let timeout = setInterval(add, 33)
```

And another

```
function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function add (x) {
  console.log(x)
  await delay(33)
  add(x + 1)
}

add(-210)
```

And... no just kidding. There are no more examples.