# How to move a DOM element inside a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a closure as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231853/370407) to move a DOM element incrementally. Eventually I want to dynamically create many of these DOM elements that should be moved independently, so that's why I'm trying to define the variable within the function.

The example from the answer given is

```
var lightning = new Array();
lightning.push($(".lightning"));

var l0 = -210;

function thunkAdd(){
  var lThis = l0;
  console.log('set lThis to '+ lThis);
  return function inc() {
    console.log('lThis = '+ lThis);
    return lThis ++;
  }
  lightning[0].css("left", lThis);
  console.log('lightning[0] left = '+lightning[0].css("left"));
}

var incrementInterval = setInterval(thunkAdd(), 33);
```

[first example on codepen](http://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/BQMMbL). Looking in the console, it seems that for some reason, `console.log('lightning[0] left = '+lightning[0].css("left"));` is not running.

A different approach I tried is:

```
var lightning = new Array();
lightning.push($(".lightning"));

var l0 = -210;
var lThis = l0;

function thunkAdd(){
  lThis ++;
  console.log('lThis = '+ lThis);

  lightning[0].css("left", lThis);
  console.log('lightning[0] left = '+lightning[0].css("left"));
}

var incrementInterval = setInterval(thunkAdd, 33);
```

[second example on codepen](http://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/Jbxxqz). That will move the image across the screen, but ideally (because the next step is to create and move many of these images dynamically) I want to define the variable `lThis` inside the `thunkAdd`function the first time it runs and then if it is defined, increment it and use the `lThis` variable to move the image. How can I do this?

Comment: Everything after `return function inc() {}` will not run, because you've exited the function by using `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments code after return will not be executed, so you never change the css left property of the element, but just increment variable.

You need to move the `lightning[0].css("left", lThis);` inside closure that's being executed with interval.

See [updated example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNOGpO?editors=1111)

You may also consider using jquery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of this (you can also do this with many elements or in loop)

`$(".lightning").animate({left: '2000px'}, 10000, 'linear');`